# Asynchronous request to Amazon Firehose

Tags: php, aws-sdk, guzzle

Is it possible to send requests to AWS asynchronously? In the real meaning.

The messages is not delivered if I'm trying to send it in a way:

```
      $firehose = new FirehoseClient($args);
      /** @var Promise\Promise $promise */
      $promise = $firehose->putRecordAsync($record);
      $promise->then(function ($result) {
          echo 'test';
      });
```

but when I add at the end of the script:

```
$promise->wait()
```

it works, but synchronously. Is there any way to make it async?

I've also tried to use a different handler:

```
    $curl = new CurlMultiHandler();
    $handler = HandlerStack::create($curl);
    $args = [
        'http_handler' => $handler,
        'region' => '#REGION#',
        'version' => 'latest',
        'credentials' => $credentials,
        'debug' => true
    ];
    $firehose = new FirehoseClient($args);

    while (!Promise\is_settled($promise)) {
        $curl->tick();
    }
```

Basically it works, but always in sync mode. What I need is to send a request to AWS and not waiting for the answer.

Comment: php is not asynchronous
you can try using rabbit mq or somehow call your script via cron using queue

Comment: I know that PHP is not async, but there is a curl function: curl_multi_exec which should be able to send a request in the background? Furthermore How should I understand the official AWS documentation: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html. It seems that there should be some way of async. Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: @Roman, there is a possibility to write async code with event-loops in PHP after it added generators (coroutines).

Comment: can you give some links where i can read about this more detailed ?

Comment: I don't have any good links to recommend. But you can google with these keywords: async generator io/event loop php :) The first link I see in my results looks good https://nikic.github.io/2012/12/22/Cooperative-multitasking-using-coroutines-in-PHP.html For deep understanding you probably will need to see some implementation on GitHub.

Comment: @Roman I don't like how those guys use terms coroutine and generator. But overall looks good, you'll get better understanding when read from diff sources :)

Comment: thank you, i understand what you mean)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best solution for your problem is to use an event loop implementation, like ReactPHP, for example.

Unfortunately, Guzzle (better say, cURL itself) is not compatible to work in an event loop out of the box.

Personally I've solved an equal problem by implementing a [bridge](https://github.com/productsupcom/guzzle-react-bridge) to run Guzzle queries event-loop-friendly. Please, take a look at [the examples](https://github.com/productsupcom/guzzle-react-bridge/tree/master/example).

So the code could look like this:

```
run(function ($loop) use ($genFn) {
    $httpHandler = new CurlMultiHandler($loop);
    $stack = HandlerStack::create($httpHandler);

    $httpClient = new Client([
        'handler' => $stack,
    ]);

    $promise = $httpClient->getAsync('https://google.com')->then(
        function ($result) { echo 'Query completed!'; },
        function ($reason) { echo 'Query failed.'; }
    );

    /*
     * The promise isn't completed yet, but the event loop will take care of it.
     * We don't need to call Promise::wait()!
     */
});
```

Comment: It seems better than standard wait(), but in my opinion it's not completely async. When you put some print function (i.e. print('TEST') at the and of run() function you can see that its waiting for some time to print it. Correct me if I'm wrong. I just want to send some piece of data to Amazon Firehose and I do not want to waste any time on sending process/request, but i feel that even in this way at the end of run() process the script is waiting for some time to send all data.

Answer (score 0):

I didn't work with async code in PHP but I did such things in Python.

From general understanding, you can't get any benefits of single async request surrounded by sync code. You should work in a fully async environment (i.e. you need some kind of outer event-loop). [ReactPHP](http://reactphp.org/) looks to be one of those.

Also, you can benefit from making several API requests simultaneously and wait for all them together. Like in this example http://docs.aws.amazon.com/aws-sdk-php/v3/guide/guide/promises.html#executing-commands-concurrently It will work faster than making several sync calls in a row.

I hope it helps.